# Apache ECharts Gauge Gradient Style

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

I am trying to get something like this, where the style of the chart goes from a color on the min value to a color on the max value, and the progress value is in between.

[image]

I have this code:

```
option = {
    tooltip: {
        formatter: '{a} <br/>{b} : {c}%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Pressure',
        type: 'gauge',
        max: 40,
        min: -10,
        startAngle: 180,
        endAngle: 0,

        progress: {
            show: true,
            itemStyle: {
                color: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    x: 0,
                    y: 1,
                    x2: 1,
                    y2: 1,
                    colorStops: [{
                        offset: 0,
                        color: "blue"
                    }, {
                        offset: 0.25,
                        color: "blue"
                    }, {
                        offset: 0.5,
                        color: "green"
                    }, {
                        offset: 0.75,
                        color: "orange"
                    }, {
                        offset: 1,
                        color: "red"
                    }],
                    global: false // default is false
                }
            }
        },
        pointer: {
            show: false
        },

        detail: {
            valueAnimation: true,
            formatter: '{value}'
        },
        data: [{
                // name of date item
                name: 'data1',
                // value of date item is 8
                value: 10,
            },
            // {
            //     name: 'data2',
            //     value: 40,
            //     // user-defined label format that only useful for this data item
            //     label: {},
            //     // user-defined special itemStyle that only useful for this data item
            //     itemStyle:{},
            //     anchor: {
            //       show: false
            //     },
            //     progress: {
            //       itemStyle: {
            //         color: 'black'
            //       }
            //     },
            //     title: {
            //       show: false
            //     },
            //     detail: {
            //       show: false
            //     },
            // }
        ]
    }]
};
```

Which gives the close to what I want but not really as you can see the range of colors apply up to the current value. To test this paste the code in here:

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-simple

The result:

[image]

Another solution is to draw the entire axis line with this gradient color and cover the right side after the progress value but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the official [custom gauge](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-gauge) example
[image]